# Update Bulk Data SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I am new to this site and I am really stuck on performing a large update for a database . I was giving a list of Transactions that needs to be updated. here is a small example of the database along with the desired output at the end
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i35QJ.jpg)

The Ask is. I have a list of transactions that the purchaseID points to PurchaseTypeID =2 and would like all the Transactions to point to a  purchaseID that has the PruchaseTypeID of 5 instead.

Comment: please add some DDL,DML,look here on how to ask and get help faster:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Sorry . Here is a better Screen Shot. @TheGameiswar

Comment: please read the link i have pasted,asking a good question has its perks ,even though it is so basic

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more detail to the logic you are looking to do.  I believe you are trying to relate based on customer.

EDIT:  Added update statement and using cte rather than temp table.

```
Create Table #Purchases (ID Int, CustomerID Int, PurchaseTypeID Int)
Insert #Purchases Values (1987, 1, 209)
Insert #Purchases Values (32875, 1, 2)
Insert #Purchases Values (628900, 3, 220)
Insert #Purchases Values (449000, 3, 30)
Insert #Purchases Values (4560, 3, 209)
Insert #Purchases Values (8008, 3, 2)
Insert #Purchases Values (9856, 3, 5)
Insert #Purchases Values (6000, 1, 5)

Create Table #Transactions (TransactionID Int, PurchaseID Int, PurchaseIDForwardTo Int)
Insert #Transactions Values (1, 1987, 32875)
Insert #Transactions Values (2, 628900, 8008)
Insert #Transactions Values (3, 449000, 8008)
Insert #Transactions Values (4, 4560, 8008)

Select * From #Purchases
Select * From #Transactions

;With ctePurchasesTransactions As
(
Select *
    From #Purchases P
    Join #Transactions T On T.PurchaseID = P.ID
)
Update T Set T.PurchaseIDForwardTo = P.ID
    From #Transactions T 
    Join ctePurchasesTransactions PT On PT.TransactionID = T.TransactionID
    Join #Purchases P On P.CustomerID = PT.CustomerID And P.PurchaseTypeID = 5

Select * From #Transactions
```

Comment: Yes you're right. Every Transaction has a purchaseID source and purchase ID destination that belong to a customerID. Every Purchase has purchaseTypeID attached to it. how do i update the Transaction.PuurchaseIDforwatdedto ? @joe C